# How to organise controllers in Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am trying to learn Angular js  I am following angular-phonecat  tutorial . I am trying to organize my controllers inside my controllers folder for that I am using this structure :

```
 app/js
     js/controllers/
        Ctrl1.js
        movies.js
```

Here everything is working fine but there is an issue suppose  I have 100 controllers then how can I use them inside my html files which is like this :

```
<!doctype html>
        <html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>My HTML File</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
          <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
          <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
          <script src="js/app.js"></script>
          <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
          <script src="js/controllers/movies.js"></script>
          <script src="js/controllers/Ctrl1.js"></script>


        </head>
        <body>

          <div ng-view></div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Is there any way by which I can reduce the calling of scripts in this line   below how can I put this in one call where these two files can be called via one or there is any other efficient way  :

```
<script src="js/controllers/movies.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/Ctrl1.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could combine all you js files in a bundle

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/angular/angular-seed.

Comment: @AndreiM what do you meany by bundle

Comment: @NilaySingh minimize all your javascript files and have all your minimized code in 1 js file. There are dozens of tools that do this.

Comment: Minimize it is ok but I am asking is there any other way like including a file which consist all the scripts link and my html file looks thin . Will that be efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution to this problem. Simply go through this tutorial :http://yeoman.io/codelab/install-generators.html And you will get to know how to install yoman, here they are using grunt here it will generate all the hard work for you .

you simply need to run this command :

```
grunt build
grunt serve:dist
```

It will create a full minified js and css  inside a dist directory and you can do whatever you want to do with that directory . You can also watch a this video  :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKiaLSJW5xI  . I hope this way you can organise your files better .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `gulp`. Gulp allows you to bundle all related files into one file which you can refer to in the `index.html`. For example, in my gulpfile I do this for all my JS files:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
 return gulp.src('./src/js/**/*.js').pipe(concat('main.js').on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js').on('error', gutil.log))
});
```

This places them all into a single file called `main.js` inside a `dist` folder which I can then deploy.

Oh - and we can then refer to this file in the index like so:

```
 %body.container-fluid
    %ui-view
  %script{ src: "js/main.js", async: true }
```

Note - This is HAML syntax not pure HTML. Also - please bear in mind that `gulp` is made it by different plugins designed to do different things - each of which will need to be installed:

```
var uglify          = require('gulp-uglify'),
// Allows me to use it in the gulpfile as uglify.foo()
```